# How to call a function from inside class to outside class

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

i want to call myfunction() inside the myfunction2()
how can i achieve that. can you give me an example.

```
class myclass(){

  function myfunction(){
  #my code here
  }

}


function myfunction2(){
# how can i get the function myfunction() here.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the () after myclass. Then in your myfunction2:

```
$obj = new myclass();
$obj->myfunction();
```

Comment: nice! it works. thankyou.